# Why does curl -V show a different OpenSSL library than ldd and curl-config?

Tags: curl, openssl

I built curl from the source (on Debian 10 machine) as follows:

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/openssl3.0/lib64 ./configure --with-openssl=/usr/local/openssl3.0`

`make`

`make install`

When I went to check the version of my new build of curl, I don't see OpenSSL 3 in the output:

```
root@ip-10-0-0-252:/usr/local/bin# /usr/local/bin/curl -V
curl 7.84.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.64.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1n zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.0.5 libpsl/0.20.2 (+libidn2/2.0.5) libssh2/1.8.0 nghttp2/1.36.0 librtmp/2.3
```

This output shows `OpenSSL/1.1.1n`.

However, curl-config looks correct:

```
root@ip-10-0-0-252:/usr/local/bin# ./curl-config  --ssl-backends 
OpenSSL v3+
```

And ldd looks correct:

```
root@ip-10-0-0-252:/usr/local/bin# ldd /usr/local/bin/curl
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffc4ddd000)
    libcurl.so.4 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007fea3312a000)
    libssl.so.3 => /usr/local/openssl3.0/lib64/libssl.so.3 (0x00007fea33082000)
    libcrypto.so.3 => /usr/local/openssl3.0/lib64/libcrypto.so.3 (0x00007fea32c20000)
...
```

Why is the output different from `curl -V` different from the others? What's the best way to prove which version of OpenSSL curl is using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the `curl -V` output again and check the *libcurl* part in particular.

I'll cut away the rest for you to make it more obvious:

```
# /usr/local/bin/curl -V
curl 7.84.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.64.0
```

curl 7.84.0, with **libcurl 7.64.0**

This tells you that when you invoke that 'curl' binary, it finds an older libcurl and not the one you built and probably intends for curl to use.

You have not configured your ld.so to find it in that path. You can edit `/etc/ld.so.conf`, set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or similar to fix it.

If you *do* edit ld.so.conf, remember to `sudo ldconfig`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Also just to add needed to run `sudo ldconfig` after editing the file.